# Uploading CSV to asset re-arranges random data

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to store randomly sampled data as an asset in GEE. When I randomly sample this data in another script it looks much like the attached .csv file (which is how I want it)

[image].

They key row is the 'classification row' which has values of either 1, 2, or 3 randomly arranged. However, if I export this in GEE directly to an asset, or download as a .csv and then upload as an asset, the data is re-arranged using the classification column, with all the 1's first, 2's second, and 3's third.

You can see I have tried adding an extra column called 'aaaa', which is just labelled 1,2,3,4 to try and overcome this, but I am still having no luck.

Where am I going wrong / does anyone have any bright ideas?

Comment: Why does it matter what order your random samples get listed in? Maybe this is a silly question (I don't have any GEE experience), but I'm thinking more generally about datasets of random points. Either you use the whole dataset, or you explicitly use a portion (select by attribute or location), but either way it doesn't matter in what order the computer is storing the point features.

Comment: I am running a classifier accuracy test whereby I give a set of experts the randomly sampled points to manually interpret. Each expert looks at say 50 points in turn, and I want them to view a range of points (classified as 1,2,3) rather than just a set of 50 points that are all classified as 1.

Comment: Got it, human users makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordering of rows is not preserved when uploading tables, because the database they are stored in prioritizes efficient *spatial* lookups (e.g. which points fall within a region of interest such as a displayed map tile) and shuffles the rows as needed to achieve this.

If you want a specific order for display or export, you **must** sort the collection by a property when you use it. Your extra column can be used for this purpose:

```js
var collection = ee.FeatureCollection('users/me/my_asset').sort('aaaa');
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, thats great.